# How to put double quote inside double quote

Tags: javascript, escaping, double-quotes

I have onclick event. And I want to put double quote inside it. for example:

```
<a
onclick="document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML='<a href="omer.php">link_2</a>'">
link
</a>
```

How can I do it? I want to put the html code inside the event without outside javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

You could circumvent the problem altogether, if you separate presentation from logic:

```
<a id="myLink">link</a>
<script>
  document.getElementById( 'myLink' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML='<a href="omer.php">link_2</a>';
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) would have to be adjusted for older IE versions before IE9 to [`attachEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility). The principle, however, stays the same.

Comment: This is good. Also worth pointing that we may face another problem if we want to support IE<8.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML='<a href=\'omer.php\'>link_2</a>'">link</a>
```

so you escape `href=\'omer.php\'`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8T2wB/